# What the plus operator does with an array?

Tags: c++

I found this code in one of Arduino libraries

```
u8 buf[6];
Host2SCS(buf+0, buf+1, Position);
Host2SCS(buf+2, buf+3, Time);
Host2SCS(buf+4, buf+5, Speed);
```

What the plus operator does with the array?

Comment: Array name decays to pointer to its first element when it's used a pointer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the expression, `buf + 1`, where `buf` is an array;

- `buf` is implicitly converted to a pointer equal to `&buf[0]` (the address of the first element of `buf`)  This is a standard conversion known (unsurprisingly) as an "array to pointer conversion", or as "decaying to a pointer".
- Adding an integral value to a pointer is normal pointer arithmetic, so the result of `buf+1` is equivalent to `&buf[1]`.

In your code as shown, the pointers resulting from adding integral values to pointers are passed to the function.  A more explicit version of your code  would be

```
u8 buf[6];
Host2SCS(&buf[0], &buf[1], Position);
Host2SCS(&buf[2], &buf[3], Time);
Host2SCS(&buf[4], &buf[5], Speed);
```

Which form is "better" is a stylistic concern - technically they are equivalent.

Answer (score -2):

`buf` is a pointer (to an array), and the `+` operator, in this context, does pointer arithmetic. For example:

```
int A[] = {5, 1, 4, 8};
std::cout << A << std::endl;
std::cout << A+3 << std::endl;

output:
0x7d972ee131c0
0x7d972ee131cc
```

so `A+3` = address of A + `3 * sizeof (int)`

Similarly, `buf+3` = address of buf + `3 * sizeof (u8)`